# Check a column of strings on another column of substrings

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to check a column of strings on another column of substrings to see the strings contain any of the substrings.

I am currently attempting  `=SEARCH(lower('Sheet2'!$A$1:$A$100),lower(B1))`   and would like a True/False response.

Thanks in advance.

An example of `Sheet2` would be:

```
    A
1   Hello
2   Hi
3   I said she
```

an example of Sheet1 with the expected result in column C would be:

```
    A            B                C
1   23  There are many          FALSE
2   45  I said he is slow       FALSE
3   3   I said she is bad       TRUE
4   78  he yelled hello         TRUE
```

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: link to example -   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2pskSYsGs12Yjbn-5gORQ22mDSaC9cSnp1nWeULlf4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet1!C1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(B:B="",,REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B:B),JOIN("|","\b"&FILTER(LOWER(Sheet2!A:A),Sheet2!A:A<>"")&"\b"))))`

You haven't shared a link to a spreadsheet, so this is untested on any actual data. Your locale is also unknown, which may required modifications as well. So if this formula doesn't work as provided, share a link to your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: link has been added to main post. thank you.   it is displaying true/false results, but they are not quite correct.

Comment: @anarchocaps the formula is correct, just change B:B to B2:B, it should look like this:

=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B2:B),JOIN("|","\b"&FILTER(LOWER(Sheet2!A:A),Sheet2!A:A<>"")&"\b"))))

Comment: The posted sample data shows as starting in A1, which is why my formula runs full column. If your data doesn't actually start in A1 as shown, then do follow Lorena Gomez' suggested modification to match your actual data.